# Llamar a un servicio SOAP desde un servidor que usa REST en JAVA

Tags: java, rest, soap

Buenas.

Tengo una aplicacion en JAVA que tiene definido servicios Rest y quiero consumir dentro de esta aplicacion servicios SOAP, esto es posible ???

Es decir al hacer una peticion GET a la URL http://localhost:8080/nombreServicio/doc?id=123 mi aplicacion internamente consuma un servicio SOAP para obtener cierta informacion y posteriormente responder a la solicitud.

Comment: ¿Por qué no va a ser posible? ¿lo dices porque te da algún error?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que es posible, con java existen diferentes tecnologias para generar un web service cliente con SOAP, entre ellas se encuentran:

- Axis - http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/present.htm
- SOAPClientSAAJ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example.

En mi opinion, yo he utilizado SOAPClientSAAJ, ya que no es necesario crear stubs con codigo innecesario, como lo hace axis.

Axis genera clases que realizan la conexión, es facil entenderlas pero en ocasiones se hace un poco revoltoso el tema, mas aun cuando el endpoint contiene varias url (metodos) que puedes consultar.

Cabe mencionar que con SOAP, al menos hasta donde he visto (si no que alguien me corrija), no existen definiciones para los endopoints en protocolo HTTP (GET, POST, etc.), solo un descriptor (wsdl)  que contiene la firma de los metodos, este descriptor es una url el cual contiene el xml de la definicion de los metodos.

Espero te sirvan de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la Información. }

Comment: En mi caso use JAX-WS Maven Plugin (http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin) que me permite generar clases para llamar a los servicios SOAP, lo único que debo tener es el WSDL y a partir de esa info el plugin se encarga de generar las clases.

Answer (score 0):

Realizar una llamada a un servicio web que devuelve una respuesta en SOAP, desde una aplicación JAVA es posible.

Saludos.